# Mysql inner join with counts in both tables

Tags: mysql

I have a products table and a changelog table. The products table has various categories (Cat 1, Cat 2, Cat3) and price levels (Level1, Level2, Level3) and I want to count and group and sort those. So I have

```
SELECT products.category,
COUNT(CASE WHEN products.price_level='1' THEN products.category END) as 'Level1',
COUNT(CASE WHEN products.price_level='2' THEN products.category END) as 'Level2',
COUNT(CASE WHEN products.price_level='3' THEN products.category END) as 'Level3'
FROM products
GROUP BY products.category
ORDER BY COUNT(products.category) DESC
```

Result is:

```
Category  Level1   Level2   Level3
Cat1       33       14        6
Cat2       19       29        10
Cat3       5        17       15
```

So far, so good..this works fine.

Now I want to bring another table in (changelog) that has a productId field that links to the products.id field. It also has a field 'status' with values Active, Inactive). So I want to add the status field to the table showing valid products, like this:

```
Category  Level1   Level2   Level3  Active
Cat1       33       14        6
Cat2       19       29       10
Cat3       5        17       15
```

So I did this which does not work:

```
SELECT products.category,
COUNT(CASE WHEN products.price_level='1' THEN products.category END) as 'Level1',
COUNT(CASE WHEN products.price_level='2' THEN products.category END) as 'Level2',
COUNT(CASE WHEN products.price_level='3' THEN products.category END) as 'Level3',
COUNT(CASE WHEN changelog.status='Active' THEN changelog.status END) as 'Active'

FROM products

LEFT JOIN changelog on products.id=changelog.productId

GROUP BY products.category
ORDER BY COUNT(products.category) DESC
```

The counts go haywire as it appears that the category counts might be accumulating for each entry in the changelog table. What is wrong with this query?

Comment: products relates to many changelogs or vice versa so the cartesean between the tables is artificially increasing the count.  you need to get the counts generated before the join.

Answer (score 0):

you must materialize the count before the join which contains more than a 1-1 relationship.

```
SELECT P.category, P.level1, p.level2, p.level3,
COUNT(CASE WHEN changelog.status='Active' THEN changelog.status END) as 'Active'
FROM (SELECT category, ID
      COUNT(CASE WHEN price_level='1' THEN category END) as 'Level1',
      COUNT(CASE WHEN price_level='2' THEN category END) as 'Level2',
      COUNT(CASE WHEN price_level='3' THEN category END) as 'Level3'
      FROM products
       GROUP BY category, ID) P
LEFT JOIN changelog 
   on p.id=changelog.productId
ORDER BY COUNT(p.category) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
SELECT t.category,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.price_level='1' THEN t.category END) as 'Level1',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.price_level='2' THEN t.category END) as 'Level2',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.price_level='3' THEN t.category END) as 'Level3',
       (SELECT COUNT(CASE 
                      WHEN c.status='Active' THEN c.status 
                    END) 
       FROM changelog AS c
       INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.id=c.productId
       WHERE p.category = t.category) AS  'Active' 
FROM products AS t       
GROUP BY t.category
ORDER BY COUNT(t.category) DESC
```

The subquery returns the count of `'Active'` records that correlate to the current product category.

Comment: This query hangs, pushes mysqld to 100% CPU. Maybe cuz there are 500k records in the changelog table?

Comment: @lilbiscuit Are your tables properly indexed?

Comment: Are the tables properly indexed? Probably not!

Answer (score 0):

Because the table *changelog* can have multiple records per product, it will multiply the counts you already had.

One way to resolve this, is by counting the active records from the *changelog* table in a sub-query, which you then join to the rest of the query:

```
SELECT    p.category,
          SUM(p.price_level='1') as 'Level1',
          SUM(p.price_level='2') as 'Level2',
          SUM(p.price_level='3') as 'Level3',
          COALESCE(c.cnt, 0)     as 'Active'
FROM      products AS p
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT   productId, 
                    COUNT(*) as cnt 
           FROM     changelog
           WHERE    status = 'Active'
           GROUP BY productId
          ) AS c
       ON c.productId = p.id
GROUP BY  p.category
ORDER BY  COUNT(p.id) DESC
```

I have also made two other changes:

- `SUM(......)` instead of `COUNT(CASE WHEN...END)`: it makes use of the fact that a boolean expression evaluates to 0 or 1; it is clearer in my opinion, shorter too;
- `ORDER BY COUNT(id)` instead of `ORDER BY COUNT(category)`: it is strange to apply an aggregate on a field you group by. Although valid in MySql, in standard SQL it would not be allowed. It is also not necessary; I find counting the `id` occurrences more readable, even though it has the same result.
- I did not use the `CASE WHEN` clause for filtering active changelog records, as it is more efficient to filter for these records via the `WHERE` clause.